# checking last char of string in c

Tags: c, string

If I have two types of strings as:

```
const char *str1 = "This is a string with \"quotes escaped at the end\""; 
const char *str2 = "This is a \"string\" without quotes at the end"; 

testFn(str1);
testFn(str2);

int testFn(const char *str)
{
  // test & return 1 if ends on no quote
  // test & return 0 if ends on quote
  return;
}
```

I would like to test if the string ends with a quote " or not

What would be a good way of testing this? Thanks

Comment: You should change that to `int testFn(const char *str)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't forget to make sure your string has at least 1 character:

```
int testFn(const char *str)
{
    return (str && *str && str[strlen(str) - 1] == '"') ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: `(expression) ? 0 : 1` is a funny way of writing `!(expression)` :)

Comment: @caf:
Maybe funny, but in this case definitely more readable.

Comment: @caf - the reason I prefer `?:` is that the entire expression reads left to right.

Answer (score 4):

```
int testFn(const char *str)
{
  return !str || !*str || str[strlen(str) - 1] != '\"';
}
```

Comment: Could crash on an empty string

Answer (score 1):

```
int testFn(const char *str)
{
  if(*str && str[strlen(str + 1)] == '"')
    return 0;
  else
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @Péter Török:
A zero-length string is a correct string. A NULL pointer does **not** describe a correct string. Passing it as an argument here violates the input specification.

I hate unnecessary checks, they kill performance (when they pile up).

Comment: @Péter Török:
I didn't. Just setting some things straight for other readers :-). I *do* believe that a NULL check is unnecessary in this case.